# pythonでXMLを操作でのエラーが発生と文字化け②

Tags: python, xml

以下のようなXMLファイルとpythonのファイルで実行しようとしているのですが、エラーが発生しどうすればエラーが消えるのかわかりません。また、文字化けも起きているのですが対処方法はありますか。（UTF-8を使用している）

**エラーコード（実行結果）**

```
C:\Users\g21125\python_xml_ex>python all-element.py
recipe
    dish
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "all-element.py", line 32, in <module>
    printAllElement(xdoc.documentElement)
  File "all-element.py", line 18, in printAllElement
    printAllElement(child, hierarchy+1)
  File "all-element.py", line 18, in printAllElement
    printAllElement(child, hierarchy+1)
  File "all-element.py", line 24, in printAllElement
    if data!='\n': print("{0}{1}".format(space, node.data))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)

C:\Users\g21125\python_xml_ex>
```

**sample.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recipe name="パン" preparations-time="5分" cokking-time="3時間">
    <dish>基本的なパン</dish>
    <material quantity='3' unit='カップ'>小麦粉</material>
    <material quantity='0.25' unit='オンス'>イースト</material>
    <material quantity='1.5' unit='カップ'>水</material>
    <material quantity='1' unit='ティースプーン'>食塩</material>
    <point>
        <process>全ての材料を一緒にして混ぜます。</process>
        <process>十分にこねます。</process>
        <process>布で覆い、暖かい部屋で1時間そのままにしておきます。</process>
        <process>もう一度こねます。</process>
        <process>パン焼きの容器に入れます。</process>
        <process>布で覆い、暖かい部屋で1時間そのままにしておきます。</process>
        <process>オーブンに入れて温度を180℃にして30分間焼きます。</process>
    </point>
</recipe>
```

**all-element.py**

```python
# coding: utf-8
# 全ての要素にアクセスする

from xml.dom import minidom

# 全ての要素のタグ名もしくはテキストを表示する
def printAllElement(node, hierarchy=0):
    # スペース調整
    space = ''
    for i in range(hierarchy*4):
        space += ' '

    # エレメントノードの場合はタグ名を表示する
    if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        print("{0}{1}".format(space, node.tagName))
        # 再帰呼び出し
        for child in node.childNodes:
            printAllElement(child, hierarchy+1)
    # テキストもしくはコメントだった場合dataを表示する
    elif node.nodeType in [node.TEXT_NODE, node.COMMENT_NODE]:
        # スペースを取り除く
        data = node.data.replace(' ', '')
        # 改行のみではなかった時のみ表示する
        if data!='\n': print("{0}{1}".format(space, node.data))

# sample.xmlファイルを読み込む
xdoc = minidom.parse("sample.xml")

# 全ての要素を表示
printAllElement(xdoc.documentElement)
```

**実行結果(正常終了)**

```
recipe
    dish
        基本的なパン
    material
        小麦粉
    material
        イースト
    material
        水
    material
        食塩
    point
        process
            全ての材料を一緒にして混ぜます。
        process
            十分にこねます。
        process
            布で覆い、暖かい部屋で1時間そのままにしておきます。
        process
            もう一度こねます。
        process
            パン焼きの容器に入れます。
        process
            布で覆い、暖かい部屋で1時間そのままにしておきます。
        process
            オーブンに入れて温度を180℃にして30分間焼きます。
```

Answer (score 1):

次の行を

```
    if data!='\n': print("{0}{1}".format(space, node.data))
```

このように書いて unicode指定にします

```
    if data!='\n': print(u"{0}{1}".format(space, node.data))
```

Answer (score 0):

# まぁ、Python3 に乗り替える、というのが一番簡単でしょうね


    <strike>if data != '\n': print("{0}{1}".format(space, node.data))</strike>

`str.format()` メソッドは unicode 文字列を str 文字列に変換(encode)しようとします。具体的には、`sys.getdefaultencoding()` で得られる encoding になります。

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

特に設定がされていない場合(default encoding)は `ascii` ですので、`UnicodeEncodeError` が発生してしまう事になります。

```
>>> "{}".format(u"あ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

対応策はいくつかあります。

### UTF-8 に変換(unicode 文字列 → str 文字列)

Python の自動変換に頼るのではなく、明示的に node.data(unicode 文字列)を str 文字列(UTF-8)に変換します。

```
if data != '\n':
  print("{0}{1}".format(space, node.data.encode('utf-8')))
```

### Default encoding を変更

Default encoding を `ascii` から `UTF-8` に変更します。

```
          :
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

# sample.xmlファイルを読み込む
xdoc = minidom.parse("sample.xml")
          :
```

### print 文(statement)を使用(sys.stdout の encoding 設定)

format() メソッドで書式を設定するのではなく、print 文を使います。

```
if data != '\n': print "%s%s" % (space, node.data)
          :

import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)

# sample.xmlファイルを読み込む
xdoc = minidom.parse("sample.xml")
          :
```

標準出力(sys.stdout)の encoding を `UTF-8` に設定します。

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
```

なお、上記の処理をソースコードに追加しなくても、環境変数 `PYTHONIOENCODING` を設定することによって同じ効果を得ることができます。

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING='UTF-8' python all-element.py
```

> **PYTHONIOENCODING**
>
> If this is set before running the interpreter, it overrides the encoding used for stdin/stdout/stderr, in the syntax encodingname:errorhandler. The errorhandler part is optional and has the same meaning as in str.encode.